# How much time does it take to affect?

Tags: gravity

We know gravitational is continuously acting on us. But let us assume that we are hanging in the space alone away from anything to affect our position. And suddenly a giant planet appear's a few million km from us then we will feel it's gravitational force on our body. But I wanted to know will it work instantly or it will take some time to take effect just like light take some time to reach us ?

Comment: Do you want an answer based on current science or future perspectives?

Comment: well if you fell comfortable in describing in both the way I will be happy because i don't know which one will i understand and what it contain's so as you wish

Comment: @Akash
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graviton

Read this.